# Query entity by primary key not working with Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, auto-generate

I am trying to query entities from my room database by id without success. Here my database:

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "artist")
data class Artist(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String,
)
```

Respository:

```
@Singleton
class AppRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val artistDao: ArtistDao
) {

    suspend fun insert(artist: Artist) {
          artistDao.insert(artist)
    }

   fun getArtist(id: Long) = artistDao.getArtist(id)
}
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE id = :id")
fun getArtist(id: Long): Flow<Day>
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ArtistViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: AppRepository,
private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

private val artistId: Long = 
        savedStateHandle.get(ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY) ?: 0

fun insert(artist: Artist) = viewModelScope.launch {
repository.insert(artist)
}

val artist =
    repository.getArtist(artistId).distinctUntilChanged().asLiveData()
}
```

Observing the artist field from `viewModel` returns always null. On the other hand when I do the same thing using the `name` field of the `Artist` entity I get some value.
I'm wondering if there are some other things to pay attention when querying by the primary key.

Comment: Try to query all the artists, and see what id are you getting for them? `"SELECT * FROM artist"`.

Comment: As your id autoincrements, it may be a different value and not the one you query

Comment: the id is set via viewModel. `private val artistId: Long = savedStateHandle.get(ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY) ?: 0`. I have query all the artist and I can see that the id I do observe is among them.

Comment: I just figured out that `savedStateHandle.set(ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY, newValue)` for setting a value is not working. I don't know why- Therefore `artistId=savedStateHandle.get(ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY) ?: 0` is always 0

Comment: Yeah, sorry but I'm not good in SavedStateHandle :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

**First** - You insert it into the database:

```
fun insert(artist: Artist) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insert(artist)
    //savedStateHandle[ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY] = artist.id
}
```

but never changing the `savedStateHandle`.

**Second**. The `artist` won't change because you initialize it at view model creation where `artistId` is 0* and `artist` has no reaction on the change of the `artistId`.

```
        val artist = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow<String>(ARTIST_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY)
                                     .mapLatest { id -> 
                           repository.getArtist(id)//suspend fun
                     }.distinctUntilChanged().asLiveData()
```